# Perl Regex new line and no character

Tags: arrays, regex, perl

I am trying extract multiple line from an Input file to Output file lines only containing head using regex in perl. Logic is to add lines as token in an array and then traverse array for head. Got stuck matching regex pattern new line and no character while adding lines as token in array.

```
my @arr = split("\n",$str);

foreach my $token (@arr) {
    print "Inside for\n";
    if($token =~ m[head])
    {
        print "Inside if";
        print $token;
    }
}
```

```
**File Content**
**InputFile.txt**

- text1
- text2
- head

- text4
- text5
- non head

- text8
- text9
- head

**OutputFile.txt**
- text1
- text2
- head

- text8
- text9
- head
```

Comment: Please, format the files using the "code" formatting. It's unclear what your input and expected output really is.

Comment: Changes are done

Comment: This is working but I have a doubt actually I have gone through file again what of there are 2-3 lines after head and that should also be included. The updated the above sample file

Comment: Instead of changing the question, ask a new one and link to the old one.

Comment: Yes posted new question :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72542841/perl-regex-new-line-and-no-character-part-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expected output can be achieved using the "sliding window" technique when reading the file line by line.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @buffer;
while (<>) {
    if (/- head$/) {
        print splice @buffer;
        print;
    } elsif (/^$/) {  # Same as ("\n" eq $_)
        @buffer = ("\n");
    } else {
        push @buffer, $_;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Can read input in paragraphs ([-00 switch](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun#-0%5Boctal/hexadecimal%5D)), if there is really always a blank like there, and print a paragraph if it has (ends with in this case) a desired pattern

```
perl -00 -wne'print if /\n\s*- head\s*\z/'  file
```

I use the `\z` [assertion](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Assertions) but `$` is fine as well in the given example.

---

In a script this is done by setting the [input record separator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$/)

```
use warnings;
use strict;

local $/ = "\n\n";

while (<>) { 
    print if /\n\s*- head\s*\z/;
}
```

We want [local](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/local) so to not change `$/` for everything in the whole run (in a larger program).

---

A comment expands the question a little so that

> ... what of there are 2-3 lines after head and that should also be included

This is simple to accommodate when a file is read in paragraphs -- just change the regex so that it matches a pattern/line anywhere (not only at the end), like

```
/\n\s*- head\s*\n/
```

This still matches if the line is at the end, as well.